# PHP - preg_replace_callback fails with sub-tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

First of all I want to apolagize if there is existing thread, I searched a lot, but could not find solution.

So I have preg_replace_callback function which replace specific tags in string with function.

Example:

```
$object = preg_replace_callback('~{FUNC\s+(.+?)}(.+?){/FUNC}~is', function($matches) use ($replace)
{
        list($condition, $function, $content) = $matches;
        return $function($content);
}, $object);
```

But when I use sub-tag inside the other tag it fails

Example:

```
{FUNC name_of_func}
    text
    text
    text
    {FUNC name_of_func2}text 2{/FUNC}
    text
    text
{/FUNC}
```

I know it finds the first closing tag and thats the problem, but im bad with regex, how to fix that so I can use multiple sub-tags or sub-sub-tags if thats possible?

Comment: It is because of your lazy quantifier which stops at the first `{/FUNC}` it encounters. When there are nested constructs, either use [**a recursive approach**](https://regex101.com/r/cxSdLh/2) or a parser altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform custom replacements of eventually nested structures using `preg_replace_callback` an easy way consists to replace innermost parts first in a `while` loop until there's nothing to replace. To do that, your pattern must forbid nested parts.

Other thing, instead of copying match arrays unnecessarily using `list()`, it's better to use named captures:

```
$replace = [
    'func1' => function ($var) { /*...*/ },
    'func2' => function ($var) { /*...*/ },
    //...
];

$pattern = '~{FUNC \s+ (?<funcName> \w+ )}
             (?<content> [^{]*+ (?: { (?!/?FUNC\b) [^{]* )*+ )
             {/FUNC}~xi';

do {
    $object = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use ($replace) {
        return $replace[$m['funcName']]($m['content']);
    }, $object, -1, $count);
} while ($count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we might want to find open and close tags that we wish to replace, collect it with `preg_match_all`, then we would be replacing it one by one by `preg_regplace` based on our patterns, similar to:

```
$re = '/{FUNC\s+(.+?)}|{\/FUNC}/mi';
$str = '{FUNC name_of_func}
    text
    text
    text
    {FUNC name_of_func2}text 2{/FUNC}
    text
    text
{/FUNC}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
    if ($match[1] != null) {
        $str = preg_replace('/({FUNC\s+)(.+?)(})/is', '$1Another new name that we wish$3', $str);
    }
    if (preg_match('/{[a-z]/is', $match[0])) {
        $str = preg_replace($match[0], '{New_FUNC}', $str);
    } elseif (preg_match('/{\//s', $match[0])) {
        $str = preg_replace($match[0], '/New_CLOS_FUNC', $str);
    } else {
        continue;
    }

}

var_dump($str);
```

#### Output

```
{FUNC Another new name that we wish}
    text
    text
    text
    {FUNC Another new name that we wish}text 2{/New_CLOS_FUNC}
    text
    text
{/New_CLOS_FUNC}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0lpdPO/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]